# Combining Awk smart ranges and jq

Tags: awk, jq

I've got a file with multiple lines in the following `json` format that I want to pipe to `jq` to extract few fields.

The format is,

```
{"userData":[{"user":{"loginName":"TEST",....]}.

{"userData":[{"user":{"loginName":"TEST1",....]}.
```

`....` represents "some" `json` data.

I can extract the lines with `awk '/{\"userData\"/{p=1}; p; /}\./{p=0};'` which seems to be printing just fine.

The difficulty I'm having is to run `jq` on each of the lines and extract the `json` fields. How can achieve this with a single `awk` command ?

Comment: Is there literally a period at the end of every object (and line)?

Comment: @JeffMercado there is. To give you some back story this is some document data from elastic search APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of that file isn't purely json if those periods are actually present at the end of the lines. *If* every line in that file is a single json object immediately followed by a period, you could read the file in raw (which passes as input every line in the file as a string), strip out the period, then parse the json and process like normal.

For example, dumping all user login names:

```
$ jq -R '.[:-1] | fromjson | .userData[].user.loginName' input.txt
```